# App Name, Form Name doesn't appear in Orbeon Forms

Tags: mysql, xml, orbeon, xforms

We are using Orbeon Forms 4.0 (M16) with MySQL db. When we create a new form it name and app name doesn't appear in `orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/summary` page. There is nothing showing. But in `orbeon_form_definition` table I see form names in form column. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Updates:

When I have commentted 
`<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="mysql"/>` 
`<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.mysql.datasource" value="mysql"/>` and used eXist db, form name, form title, desc and app appeared in summary page `/orbeon/fr/orbeon/builder/summary`. So I suppose that problem with MySQL persistence layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to avernet answer: [link](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/598#issuecomment-10830085) we have to do: 
Patch the `apps/fr/persistence/mysql/search.xpl` in your WEB-INF/lib/orbeon-form-runner.jar as done in [link](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/dfd75204be499e26c82aafea0792d2804594b960). 
I have done it and now it works.

Comment: BTW, don't forget to mark your own answer and the correct answer.

Comment: @avernet, I know, but the stackoverflow system doesn't allow to mark my answer: `You can accept your own answer in 6 hours`